# Returning multiple ints as a single value

Tags: java, oop

Hey I'm working on a method that picks the smallest digit from the ones, tens, hundreds, and thousands place on two passed integers and then returns an int made of the smallest values for each place. For example if int a= 4321 and int b=1957 then the method would return 1321. This is my code so far, I think I got everything but I cant find out how to properly return the new value as an integer.

```
public static int biggestLoser(int a, int b){
    int first;
    int second;
    int third;
    int fourth;
    if(a>9999 || a<1000 || b>9999 || b<1000){
        if(a>b)
            return b;
        else
            return a;
        }
    else{
        if(a%10 < b%10)
            first=a%10;
        else
            first=b%10;
        if(a/1000<b/1000)
            fourth=a/1000;
        else
            fourth=b/1000;
        if(a/100%10<b/100%10)
            second=a/100%10;
        else
            second=b/100%10;
        if(a/10%10<b/10%10)
            third=a/10%10;
        else
            third=b/10%10;
        //int total=fourth,third,second,first;?????
        //return total;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider multiplying by 10's and adding, exactly as you'd do on paper. Don't make it any more complicated then what it is -- basic 3rd grade arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your code has a minor error. You have to swap the codes for `second` and `third`.

```
if(a/100%10<b/100%10)
    third=a/100%10;
else
    third=b/100%10;
if(a/10%10<b/10%10)
    second=a/10%10;
else
    second=b/10%10;
```

After fixing it simply say:

```
int total = first + 10 * second + 100 * third + 1000 * fourth;
return total;
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can either form a string first and do an `Integer.parseInt()` or do some math like `int total = (first*1)+(second*10)+(third*100)+(fourth*1000);`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to implement something like this:

```
int returnValue = 0;
for(int digit = 0; digit < 4; digit++) {
    int aDigit = (a / Math.pow(10, digit)) % 10; // Gets the digit
    int bDigit = (b / Math.pow(10, digit)) % 10;
    int max = (a > b)? a : b; // Calculates de maximum digit
    returnValue += max * Math.pow(10, digit); //Adds the new digit to the return value
}
return returnValue;
```

Comment: Math.pow is very inefficient whereas he simply needs to multiply integers.

Comment: Thanks but its a bit too complex!

Answer (score 0):

```
int i=1000,z=0;
  do{
   int x = a/i;
   a=a%i;
   int y = b/i;
   b=b%i;
   if(x<y)
     z+=x*i;
   else z+=y*i;
   i=i/10;
}while(i>0);
 return z;
//this is just logic, works for 4 digit numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

just return the values as an int array. I have refactored your method to do this

```
public static int[] biggestLoser(int a, int b){
int first;
int second;
int third;
int fourth;
int [] values;
if(a>9999 || a<1000 || b>9999 || b<1000){
    if(a>b)
        return b;
    else
        return a;
    }
values = new int[4];
else{
    if(a%10 < b%10)
        first=a%10;
    else
        first=b%10;
    if(a/1000<b/1000)
        fourth=a/1000;
    else
        fourth=b/1000;
    if(a/100%10<b/100%10)
        second=a/100%10;
    else
        second=b/100%10;
    if(a/10%10<b/10%10)
        third=a/10%10;
    else
        third=b/10%10;
    //int total=fourth,third,second,first;?????
    values[0] = first;
    values[1] = second;
    values[2] = third;
    values[3] = fourth;
    return value;
}
```

}

in your main method you can now get each element of the array via a for loop

```
 for(int x : values){
     System.out.print(x);
 }
```